# Do I need to install Xcode 4.5 to submit iOS app to App store?

Tags: ios, app-store, xcode4.5

After seeing [this cocos2d topic](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/41104) I became confused. Do I need to install Xcode 4.5 to submit my app to iOS App Store?

Comment: Do i need Xcode4.5 to submit app to App Store, or can i just use Xcode 4.4 to do the same thing?

Comment: I heard someone said that all iOS apps must be built with iOS6 SDK!
I just want to support iOS 5 not iOS6, must i use Xcode 4.5 to build and submit to app store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, if your app does not require any iOS 6 APIs or features, you do not need to install Xcode 4.5 to submit apps to the App store.

Apple may change this requirement at some unknown point in the future.  For instance, when the  SDK for iOS 4.0 was publicly released, Apple stopped allowing the submission of apps developed with the, over 1 year older, 2.x SDKs.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments imply if your deployment target is ios5.1 or older you can use older Xcodes to do this. I just did this last night. That said, if some library you want to include was built against the new ios6 SDK, then you will probably not get your app to link. In this case you will have to update Xcode to 4.5.